# How to include args and kwargs in a Protocol?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to write Protocol to ensure that a given function includes an initial parameter. mypy is happy if I make the Protocol definition only support that single parameter, but complains when I add `*args` and `**kwargs` to support additional arbitrary ones.

```py
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar, Dict, Any

T = TypeVar("T", covariant=True)

class Func(Protocol[T]):
    def __call__(self, ctx: Dict[Any, Any], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> T:
        pass

def f(ctx: Dict[Any, Any]) -> str:
    return "hello"

def ff(ctx: Dict[Any, Any], *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> str:
    return "hello"

a: Func[str] = f  # mypy complains here
b: Func[str] = ff # but not here
```

Is this possible? Or is there a way to tell mypy to only type check the first param and not the existence of the rest?

I don't want to use a `Callable[..., T]` since that doesn't enforce the `ctx` parameter.

I'm looking for this behavior:

```py
def f(ctx: Dict[Any, Any]) -> str:
    return "hello"

def ff(ctx: Dict[Any, Any], x: int) -> str:
    return "hello"

def fff(ctx: Dict[Any, Any], x: int = 0) -> str:
    return "hello"

def ffff(x: int) -> str:
    return "hello"

a: Func[str] = f    # yes
b: Func[str] = ff   # yes
c: Func[str] = fff  # yes
d: Func[str] = ffff # no
```

The function definition can include any number of additional arguments, just as long as the first one is the `Dict`, so that I can write a function that looks like:

```py
def accept_func(func: Func)

accept_func(f)    # type ok
accept_func(ff)   # type ok
accept_func(fff)  # type ok
accept_func(ffff) # type bad
```

Comment: The error's correct, `f` **can't** be called with arbitrary positional or keyword parameters. If you say `def __call__(self, ctx: Dict) -> T:` in the protocol (or just `Func = Callable[[Dict], T]`) it's fine, because a function that _can_ accept additional parameters doesn't _have_ to, but the opposite isn't true.

Comment: I see what you're saying -- i think what i'm actually looking for is "the function *definition* can include any number of additional arguments, just as long as the first one is `Dict[Any, Any]`

Comment: `ff` is **not** like the others, though - if you called it with _only_ a context dictionary that would be a type error (just as it would for `ffff` when it tried to treat the first argument as an int when it's a dict).

Comment: Are you looking for `Concatenate` and `ParamSpec` (or only `ParamSpec` if you insist on using protocol)? You can make your protocol generic in paramspec `_P` and use `_P.args` and `_P.kwargs` to annotate `args` and `kwargs` then. (or just `Callable[Concatenate[dict[Any, Any], _P], T]`, and even `Callable[Concatenate[dict[Any, Any], ...], T]` in future when type checkers begin to support literal ellipsis there, python 3.11 already does).

Answer (score 0):

Mypy complains because if a variable has a type of `Func[str]`:

```
a: Func[str] = f
```

then you should logically be able to do:

```
a({'the answer': 42}, 1, 2, 3, other_stuff="hello")
```

because the interface of `Func` specifies that it accepts arbitrary arguments.

Your `f` function does not, though, so it doesn't conform to `Func`.

What you actually want to do is make the signature of `Func` *more* restrictive:

```
class Func(Protocol[T]):
    def __call__(self, ctx: Dict[Any, Any]) -> T:
        pass
```

Both `f` and `ff` can be called with this signature, so they both conform to `Func`.

Comment: i edited my q for clarification, but making it more restrictive the way you're suggesting doesn't work. i think a better phrasing of my q might be "how to only enforce part of a signature"

Comment: Seems XY to me.  What are you hoping to be able to *do* with a variable of type `Func`?  You'd never be able to call it since the different signatures you describe in your edit are mutually exclusive -- and what's the point of defining an interface that nobody can ever use?  I have a strong suspicion that whatever problem you're trying to solve would actually be better solved by a unit test than by static typing.

Comment: There are a lot of weeds, but at runtime I know the valid invocation of the function so I am always able to call it. Those are 3 separate function signatures, but by requirement they all share that first argument. I'd like to provide that information through the typing system (for other users) -- i can do a separate runtime check to see if the func signature is valid but the typing is some added info that i think would be nice

Comment: if you imagine the docs, they'd say something like "supply any function you want as long as the first argument is a Dict."

Comment: If you have 3 specific signatures, I'd just do a union type of those 3 signatures, rather than trying to generalize.

Comment: it was just an example -- there are an infinite number of possible signatures. I just want a type that literally conveys "provide any function with any signature as long as the first argument is of type Dict"